# Checkbox not showing up in md-select multiple

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, md-select

I am trying to enable multi select in my md-select. I have hardcoded `multiple` to true but md-select isn't showing `checkbox` besides the value in the drop down list.

I am using AngularJS 1.4.8 and AngularMaterial 1.0.0.

Code:

```
<div style="background: #f7f7f7" ng-controller="CircleTimeActivityPageController">

            <md-input-container flex="30">
                     <md-select multiple="true" placeholder="Observations" ng-model="myData">
                          <md-option ng-value="selectedObservation" ng-repeat="selectedObservation in observations">
                                    {{ selectedObservation }}</md-option>
                     </md-select>
            </md-input-container>

 </div>

mainApp.controller('CircleTimeActivityPageController', function($scope, $http, $mdToast, $log) {
    $scope.observations = [1.3, 1.2, 1.1];
});
```

[image]
[image]

Please excuse my ignorance in AngularJS and AngularMaterial.

**EDIT:**

CODEPEN Example: https://codepen.io/wingoku/pen/ZLYxNY

Best Regards

Comment: Don't understand your problem. Your  `$scope.observations = [];` looks empty and where is checkbox?

Comment: its empty in this code but its updated in the app. I'll update the code with values

Comment: Don't understand your problem exactly.

Comment: Please see the updated question. There are supposed to be CHECKBOX on the left of the number values but they are not visible for some reason

Comment: Still not understood your problem.

Comment: I have added codepen example too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just a version issue.
If you upgrade `angular-material` version to the latest **1.1.1**, your problem will be fixed, as you can see in this [working plunker](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpJqmj).

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script>
...
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @troig the checkbox still does not show if we try to bind `multiple` to an attribute by using `ng-multiple` as discussed [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5459). You can try fiddling your codepen demo change `multiple` to `ng-multiple="true"`. The check-boxes won't show. Any fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

Angular-material 1.0 doesn't display checkboxes in `select multiple` dropdowns - instead, the color of the selected elements changes. In your codepen example it's difficult to see since the theme color is so close to the default, unselected black - check out [the same example with a pink theme instead](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJYGWY) and you'll see it's much easier to see. The functionality should be there regardless of checkboxes.

If you want to have the checkboxes, you'll need to use a newer version of angular-material - for example the 1.1.0 version has those.

Comment: It does show checkbox in the AngularMaterial demo https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select

Comment: That's version 1.1.0 - if you want the checkboxes there natively, you need to use that version instead of 1.0